# Resource Not Found While fetching contacts from MS Graph API

Tags: outlook, azure-active-directory, botframework, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I tried below github sample for Azure AD Authentication and successfully getting access token with proper call back URL.

[https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/18.bot-authentication](https://jwt.ms)

Modified and Configured Web.config Keys as per my application created in https://apps.dev.microsoft.com

```
  <add key="ActiveDirectory.Mode" value="v1" />
<add key="ActiveDirectory.ResourceId" value="https://graph.microsoft.com" />
<add key="ActiveDirectory.EndpointUrl" value="https://login.microsoftonline.com" />
<add key="ActiveDirectory.Tenant" value="xyz-xyz" />
<add key="ActiveDirectory.ClientId" value="xyz-xyz" />
<add key="ActiveDirectory.ClientSecret" value="xyz-xyz" />
 <add key="ActiveDirectory.RedirectUrl" value="http://localhost:3979/api/Callback" />
<add key="ActiveDirectory.Scopes" value="Calendars.Read,Calendars.ReadWrite,Contacts.Read,Contacts.ReadWrite,Mail.Read,Mail.ReadWrite,User.Read" />
```

I had crossed checked access token that i received [jwt.ms](https://jwt.ms). It is a valid token with scopes defined exactly as i defined in web.config.

I am able to get User Profile data from API by passing token but while trying to call "Contacts" of user, I am getting below error.

```
{
"error": {
    "code": "ResourceNotFound",
    "message": "Resource could not be discovered.",
    "innerError": {
        "request-id": "6f0f3ec9-76c9-4662-ac25-0bc73f887268",
        "date": "2019-03-02T17:23:35"
    }
}
```

}

Code calling Contact API call.

```
   //Get Logged in user contacts
    public async Task<IUserContactsCollectionPage> GetMyContactsAsync()
    {
        var graphClient = GetAuthenticatedClient();
        IUserContactsCollectionPage contacts = await graphClient.Me.Contacts.Request().GetAsync();
        return contacts;
    }
```

FYI: Displayed Sign In card in emulator Authorize sample URL is like below

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/a76b43b0-3088-4c56-ba0d-01f317b1f18c/oauth2/authorize?resource=https:%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com&client_id=XYZ&response_type=code&haschrome=1&redirect_uri=http:%2F%2Flocalhost:3979%2Fapi%2FCallback&x-client-SKU=PCL.Desktop&x-client-Ver=3.13.9.1126&x-client-CPU=x64&x-client-OS=Microsoft+Windows+NT+10.0.16299.0&state=<stateID>
```

Comment: Do you get a response if you reduce your code to
await graphClient.Me.Request().GetAsync();

Comment: The request you mentioned is to read use profile , I am successfully able to get response for same. I tried in postman also for "me/contacts" request with a valid token, yet same error am getting

Comment: Thanks , please try to use Fiddler to capture the actual call to the graph (https://graph.microsoft.com). Log into [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) using the same user account that you are using into your app and try that call that very URl, does that give you a response?

Comment: Yes, Its giving response.Not only for Contact but also for Photo.

Comment: @PavanKumarGVVS is there anything else that I can help you on this?

Answer (score 2):

It might happens for many reasons; one of the very common issues is to required grant permission to your registered app. Make sure you have done the following steps.

Step 1:

Login in to your portal and select your application under app registrations. Then click on settings see the screen shot below:

[image]

Step 2:

Once you've clicked Settings, a new window will come up on the right side, click on Required Permission menu. See the screen shot below:

[image]

Step 3:

Select Required Permission Menu and assign your permission by clicking on Add button. See the snap below:

[image]

Step 4:

Click on Select an API option, see below:

[image]

Final Step:

Select your desired API, and check which you want access for. Once finished the permission click on Done. After this step you can access your required resource / Scope from your application. See the screen shot below:

[image]

Comment: I had already done the steps you mentioned. I even gave grant both application and delegate permissions for the request I need.

Comment: Please refer to  Use https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/hybrid_rest_support  REST APIs to access mailboxes in Exchange hybrid deployments to check if all requirements are met for the REST API to work in Hybrid environments

Comment: You are using V1.0 endpoint make sure you are not using Microsoft personal account for this.  personal account does not support for V1.0

Comment: For more details you can have look on known issues on Microsoft graph API https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/known-issues

Comment: Thanks and Yes after a long hours , I came to understand that by implement and testing with V1.0 and V2.0 endpoints. Finally fixed it a few hours back.

Comment: V2.0 endpoint will not work for the applications created in Azure AD in azure portal.

Comment: @PavanKumarGVVS partially correct Microsoft still recommended to use V1.0. As V2.0 in preview but some feature is working fine and it is in continuous enhancement. Thanks

Comment: How do you know Microsoft personal account is not supported for version 1.0? In what other way then are we allowed to use Graph API?

Comment: What did you mean by `version 1.0`? and the context was for  2019 is not comparable now. Whats your query? Be more specific!

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron - I am getting ResourceNotFound error while accessing https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendar for my personal account. Are personal accounts still not supported via v1?

Comment: Yes supported but you need `Calendars.Read, Calendars.Read.Shared, Calendars.ReadWrite` dedicated permission please [docs here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-calendars?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#http-request)