# Develop .netcore web api with open id connect security while accessing

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-webapi, openid-connect

we have a website which is accessible after azure AD authentication with Open ID connect.

So now the requirement is, we need to develop a .net core web api and need to access this web api from above website.

Need some guidance on developing this web api and how can we access this web api from website securely. Can we use the token method or the JWT or any other way instead of secret key and api key.

Please share any useful link if possible.

Much Thanks
Anuraj

Comment: If the answer helped you to figure out your problem you can mark it so that it would helpful to others

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For dotnet core web API project sample you can see [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-openidconnect-aspnetcore)  which build on using openID connect.

Once you have build API you need to register it on azure portal. Beside you have assign permission on your application which you are looking forward to access from out side.

Here you can have a look on [how to register app on azure portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-protocols-openid-connect-code)

After successful registration make sure you have allowed API permission you need like below screen shot:

[image]

Here is same thread for [API permission guide line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54961425/resource-not-found-while-fetching-contacts-from-ms-graph-api/54965024#54965024) you can have a look on.

This is also helpful for you to test it on [postman example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54969181/any-example-for-this-specific-ad-flow/54975900#54975900).

IF you have any complexities regarding implementation let me know. Thanks

Comment: Something similar to this what i was expecting. Thanks Md Farid.

Comment: @AnurajRajagopal If the answer  was helpful for you click on the check mark beside the answer to help other. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can rely on [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio) to understand how to properly create a .NET Core Web API with MVC.

Also yes you can use token or JWT or OAuth2 or any authentication method. Here's an useful link: https://auth0.com/blog/securing-asp-dot-net-core-2-applications-with-jwts/

You can then try to code something and eventually ask a more specific problem about coding here in SO.